# Finding embedding dimentions of the HuggingFace model

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, llama-index, faiss

I try to figure out how to use `faiss` Vectore Store with `LlamaIndex`.

Instruction says, that I must indicate vector dimensions in advance. Here is the code:

```
    import faiss

    # dimensions of text-ada-embedding-002
    d = 1536
    faiss_index = faiss.IndexFlatL2(d)
```

So, dimensions of `text-ada-embedding-002` model is `1536`.

I want to use `BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5` model.

What does embedding vector dimensions it outputs?
How do I find the output vector dimensions of other transformer models? Do I need to run the models and measure the results, or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension for bge-small-en-v1.5 is 384.
You can find it on the model page https://huggingface.co/BAAI/bge-small-en-v1.5, you will find a table with dimension, sequence length and scores.

Also, when loading a model via transformers.AutoModel you can more details on the loaded model using model.eval() likes input dimensions, layers, output, etc.